# Why all my data coming in one line in normal notepad ? Please provide the solution

Tags: notepad

When I downloaded a text file from the server.

1. If I open the same file in normal notepad. I am getting all text in one Line.
2. If I open the same file with other editor I am getting in proper format.

Example : **test.txt**
in **normal notepad**

123456789012|24-02-2015 15:48|Balance Enquiry|Failure123456789012|24-02-2015 15:48|Balance asking|Failure123456789012|24-02-2015 15:48|Balance checking|Failure123456789012|24-02-2015 15:48|Balance finding|Failure

**test.txt**
in in other editors like **notepad++,wordpad etc**

123456789012|24-02-2015 15:48|Balance Enquiry|Failure

123456789012|24-02-2015 15:48|Balance asking|Failure

123456789012|24-02-2015 15:48|Balance checking|Failure

123456789012|24-02-2015 15:48|Balance finding|Failure

Answer (score 0):

On the *Menu Bar*, goto:
1. `Format`
2. Select (Tick) `Word Wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

On Unixoid systems a linebreak is indicated by a Linefeed-character (`x0A`), while Windows uses two characters: Carriage-return (`x0D`) + Linefeed (`x0A`).
Your textfile seems to use the former while Windows' notepad.exe can only handle the latter - while other tools recognize both.

If you need to you can convert it using notepad++ by going to `Edit`-> `EOL Conversion` -> `Windows Format` - but I'd rather stay away from standard notepad and use notepad++ instead.